# MERGE conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, insert

I've this updatescript in which I load new data into my db or update existing data. But I get these errors.

```
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
"FK_xx_MaterialDataxxx_xxxx_MaterialText". 
 The conflict occurred in database "TEST", table "dbo.xx_MaterialData", column 'xxxxxGUID'.
```

and

```
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
"FK_xx_MaterialData_xxxx_Material". The conflict occurred in 
database "TEST", table "dbo.xxxx_Material", column 'xxxxxGUID'.
```

This are the statements which are relevant. But of course there are a lot more `MERGE` statements with a lot more tables.

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[xx_MaterialDataxxx] ON xxxxxGUID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 

MERGE INTO [dbo].[xxxx_Material] ON xxxxxGUID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 

MERGE INTO [dbo].[xx_MaterialData] ON xxxxxGUID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
```

`FK_xx_MaterialDataxxx_xxxx_MaterialText` and `FK_xx_MaterialData_xxxx_Material` are set to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Maybe is this a problem of the order I put the `MERGE` statements? Or do you know what could be the reason?

And another question: When I run the script again there are no errors. So is it OK to just run the scipt twice or could this cause problems in the future?

Comment: Order your `merge` statements based on dependency. e.g. `cMat_Material` should be after `JW_MaterialData` based on your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to put the `MERGE` statements in the right order by looking at the dependencies of the tables.

1. `xxxx_Material`
2. `xx_MaterialData`
3. `xx_MaterialDataxxx`