# MERGE conflict foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, foreign-keys, constraints

I use `MERGE` to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` data into my database. But when I `MERGE` into my tables `xx_MaterialData` or `xx_MaterialDataxxx` I get FK errors as seen below.

```
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_xx_MaterialData_xxxx_Material". The conflict occurred in database 
"TEST", table "dbo.xxxx_Material", column 'xxxxxGUID'.
```

and

```
The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_xx_MaterialDataxxx_xxxx_MaterialText". The conflict occurred in
database "TEST", table "dbo.xx_MaterialData", column 'xxxxxGUID'.
```

I've already tried different order of the `MERGE` statements but didn't help. I tried first `xxxx_Material` and then the cildren. Or first the child `xx_MaterialDataxxx` and then `xx_MaterialData` and then `xxxx_Material`.

The dependencies are these:
`xxxx_Material` > `xx_MaterialData` > `xx_MaterialDataxxx`
`xxxx_Material` > `xxxx_MaterialText`
`xxxx_PriceList` > `xx_MaterialDataxxx`

Does anyone have an idea what else I can do? I've another database with the same structure but not the same data and there I don't have the problem.

What is the proper order of the `MERGE` statements? Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide your queries and table structure?

Comment: Please run SELECT to verify before you update, insert, delete anything. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MERGE conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255336/merge-conflict-with-the-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was still a problem with the order of the statements. After putting them again in a proper order it worked.